# Forecasting with LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, forecasting

I have the following question, I have already created a forecasting model but it doesn't really predict the future, I just have a bunch of data, I split it into a "training" sample and into a "testing" sample and then I can check how good is my prediction. But now I want to forecast for the next 10 days that are not in the data I have. How on earth can I do it?

Example : Let's say I have the data for these days:

04-07-2017: 213

05-07-2017: 321

06-07-2017: 111

07-07-2017: 90

08-07-2017: 78

Now I want to forecast the data for the next 3 days. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look into this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: stop creating fake accounts to post questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44984245/1090562

Comment: Sorry, I ask because I need answers. I will keep doing this till I get my answer. Have a great day Dali

Comment: @Francisco - creating duplicated questions and account will rather lead to blocking your accounts than to the answer, instead try to follow what community suggests (improving quality of the question) and people will be more than happy to help (that what SO is about in the end).

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you could use encoder/decoder. Something similar to seq2seq as in NLU.